# Can I place all the meta tags in a div tag within header?

Tags: html

Currently, I place all the meta tags in a div within Header. I wrote an AMD module to access those meta tags using the div.

```
<div id="serverInfo">
     <meta id="environment" name="environment" content="DEV" />
     <meta id="build-id" name="build-id" content="a123s" />
</div>
```

Comment: You can do whatever you like. It won't be valid HTML though.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

In the header? **No.**

A `<div>` inside of your `<head>` is completely invalid.

However, `<meta>` tags *are* valid within the `<body>` section of your page, under specific circumstances.

If you're using HTML5 and were to replace your `<div>` container with a *phrasing element*, it would actually be considered valid.

---

[**Source**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-meta-element)

> **4.2.5 The meta element**
>
> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>
> If the itemprop attribute is present: where phrasing content is expected.

> **Phrasing content** is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.
>
> a (if it contains only phrasing content), abbr, area (if it is a descendant of a map element), audio, b, bdi, bdo, br, button, canvas, cite, code, command, datalist, del (if it contains only phrasing content), dfn, em, embed, i, iframe, img, input, ins (if it contains only phrasing content), kbd, keygen, label, map (if it contains only phrasing content), mark, math, meter, noscript, object, output, progress, q, ruby, s, samp, script, select, small, span, strong, sub, sup, svg, textarea, time, u, var, video, wbr, text

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not allow `<div>` elements within the `<head>` element.

Since the start and end tags for the `<head>` and `<body>` are optional, trying to do so will implicitly end the `<head>`, start the `<body>` and put the `<div>` there … and the `<meta>` elements will just be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you? Yes you can. But it's not a good idea. The fact that you are asking this shows that you already know this.

[The HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#meta) expects meta tags to be direct children of the head. Browsers expect the same. If you were to put something like a charset or descriptions into the document in this manner, it is highly likely they would be ignored by the browser and search engines.

Why do you want to put them in a div? Why in a meta tag?

Would you be better off putting it in a hidden form or something?

Comment: No, you can't. If you try then the opening `<div>` tag will implicitly end the `<head>` and start the `<body>` so the element will end up in the `<body>`

Comment: When I say you can, I am referring mostly to how browsers tend to munge html until it is something they understand. This is why people think they can do a lot of things that actually don't work. (@j08691's comment on the main question captures this nicely)